# Android BLE is connecting to multiple devices at once

Tags: android, android-ble, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've seen plenty of questions about how to connect to multiple devices purposely. But in my situation, I am only trying to connect to one hardware device.

I have two hardware devices that are supposed to do the same thing. When they connect to my app via BLE, then they have an LED that turns a solid color. This all works fine and dandy when I only have one device turned on. However, when I turn two of the devices on and then try to connect to just one. *Both* of the devices' LED's turn solid. Although I don't seem to be getting any incoming data from the one that I didn't intend to connect to.

I don't think it's the device's fault. Because I don't have this issue on iOS. I think the phone might be remembering previously connected devices somewhere maybe?

I'm sorry, this is a lot of code. But I feel like it's important to have this whole class. Any help is much appreciated.

```
package com.roberts.croberts.orange;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;

import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@TargetApi(21)
public class BluetoothRegulator {

    private static BluetoothRegulator instance = null;

    private Context context;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;

    private BluetoothDevice orangeDevice;
    //scanner stuff
    private Handler mHandler;

    // Stops scanning after 3 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 3000;

    //connected stuff
    private android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();

    private Handler foundHandler = new Handler();
    private Handler servicesHandler = new Handler();

    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;

    public static BluetoothRegulator sharedInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new BluetoothRegulator();
            Log.i("chase", "created new instance");
        }
        return instance;
    }
    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                Log.i(TAG, "BR: onconnectionsStateChanged Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // Loops through available GATT Serviceokay so ees.
                for (BluetoothGattService gattService : mBluetoothGatt.getServices()) {
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattService.getCharacteristics()) {
                        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                        Log.i(TAG, mBluetoothGatt == null ? "mbluetooth is null" : "should be subscribed");
                    }
                }
                Log.i("chase", "did connect and discover devices");
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Not Success onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                connect(orangeDevice);
            }
        }
        private Object getFieldFromObject(Object obj, String name){
            try {
                Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field.get(obj);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("chase", "e: "+e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.i("BR: chase", "received data!");
        }
    };


    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    public boolean initialize(android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager btmanager, Context ctx) {
        mBluetoothManager = btmanager;
        context = ctx;
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            setUpCallBack();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void scan() { //we call scan when they hit the connect button...
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        Log.i("chase", "start scanning");
        devices = new ArrayList<>();
        if (mHandler == null) mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                }
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }
    private void foundDevice(BluetoothDevice device){
        final String deviceName = device.getName();

        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 5 && (deviceName.substring(0, 6).equals("orange") || deviceName.substring(0, 6).equals("smartb"))) {
            for (BluetoothDevice d : devices){
                if (d.getAddress().equals(device.getAddress())){
                    return;
                }
            }
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            devices.add(device);
            if (devices.size() == 1) { //wait one second and then assume there aren't any more devices named "orange"
                foundHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        doneSearching();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
    private void doneSearching(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
        if (devices.size() == 1){
            BluetoothDevice device = devices.get(0);
            connect(device);
        }else{
            //normally this displays a list and the user can choose which device. But this works just as well for now.
            BluetoothDevice device = devices.get(0);
            connect(device);
        }
    }
    //connect method
    public boolean connect(BluetoothDevice btdevice) {
        orangeDevice = btdevice;
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || btdevice == null || btdevice.getAddress() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
        devices = new ArrayList<>();
        mBluetoothGatt = orangeDevice.connectGatt(context, true, mGattCallback);
        return true;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) return;
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                foundDevice(device);
            }
        };

    public void setUpCallBack(){
        mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                foundDevice(device);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("Chase", "Scan Failed Error Code: " + errorCode);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Update

I was playing around with a galaxy tablet and wasn't able to recreate the issue. So I think it's device dependent. The problem occurs on the Galaxy S3, and I am trying to round up some other devices to test with.

Also, I was able to get my hands on some new devices and it seems that if the device has never been connected before to the phone (virgin device) then that device doesn't get mixed up and think it's connected when it's not. So we will see it when we search but it never thinks I am connecting to it, until I actually do connect to it. After that, then half the time it thinks I am trying to talk to it when I am not. I hope that makes sense. Which backs up the theory that the phone is somehow caching old devices. I tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling it to see if it would have the same effect as using a virgin device, but it seems the app has nothing to do with it. The device will still connect (when it's not supposed to) after it has been introduced to the phone, even if I did a fresh install of the app.

Comment: Since you are calling done searching method inside a handler having delay of 1000ms, there can be a chance when this method is called your devices arraylist gets changed to different size and it misses the if(devices.size()==1) and falls into else and connects both of devices. So please check for the size of devices arraylist

Comment: Gautum, I'm not following. doneSearching() only get's called after a device has been found and only ever get's called one time (so it should only connect one device). I don't see any race condition or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the BLE devices themselves. Is there a chance that they might have the same System ID ? I believe it's the first characteristic in 0x180A. If so - it will be difficult for the host to distinguish them and such a double connection might happen.

Comment: Also check for a duplicate MAC/hardware address, though that would typically manage to confuse iOS too.

Comment: I don't think they have the same hardware address. The devices have unique UUID's (I'm assuming that's the only hardware address). & I've sent this thread to the hardware guy to confirm. But, @DrivingSimulatorGuy, I I'm a little confused what you mean by the first characteristic in 0x180A. Can you elaborate?

Comment: UUIDs are not a hardware address. Let's say you have 2 separate BLE devices that have the same service - let's say accelerometer. They will have the same UUIDs for those services. Furthermore one BLE device frequently has many UUIDs to address services inside it. A hardware address or sometimes people would call it MAC is a number that is unique to a BLE device. (calling is MAC is not quite correct as it is a 8-byte number, while a MAC is a 6-byte number)

Comment: A System ID is a unique 8-byte number for every BT radio chip. Depending on the software stack used in the firmware of those BLE devices that number can be reprogrammed, so for instance if you upload the same binary code to both sensors it might make their System ID the same, although most systems that I saw would not do that.

Comment: Every GATT server that is a part of a BLE device has a couple of services that are always there. I.e. 0x1800, 0x1801 and 0x180A. Then - go the services addressable via the UUIDs. Look at this GATT services table as an example and find the System ID there: [TI SensorTag GATT Server](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

-Lets say you have 2 devices. So foundDevice() gets called. Now devices arraylist contains 1 device.

-After that you are using handler which calls doneSearching() & checks

```
if device.size()==1
```

It returns true and you call connect()

-Inside connect you are again creating an arraylist i.e

```
devices = new ArrayList<>();
```

So what happens now is your devices ArrayList<>() contains 0 elements.

-So now when 2nd device is found again the above steps are repeated because whenever connect method is getting called, the size of list is getting refreshed to 0
So just remove the line

```
 devices = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside connect() method

Comment: This could be a problem. But it's not the problem I am having. Every time I have run the code devices has had two items in it when doneSearching() is called. Moreover, doneSearching calls stopScan(), so new devices aren't being found after that point.